# Lazy DataModel with multi column sorting not working

Tags: primefaces

using LazyDataModel with multiple sorting I am getting NullPointerException. When I am using sortMode="multiple", the load method is taking null values at attribute 
List multiSortMeta

my xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup id="processPanel">
            <p:dataTable id="processTable" value="#{hubProcessBean.processModel}"
                var="process" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                 rows="5" lazy="true" sortBy="#{process.transactionId}" sortOrder="ascending" rows="5" lazy="true" sortMode="multiple" resizableColumns="true">
```

and in the bean I am calling

```
processModel_ = new TransactionLazyDataModel(criteria);
```

and my LazyDataModel is

```
@Override
    public List<Transaction> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String,String> filters) {
        try {
            HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
            transactionList = transactionHome.loadByCriterion(criterias_,first, pageSize, multiSortMeta);
            for (Transaction tr : transactionList) {
                Hibernate.initialize(tr.getAgency());
                Hibernate.initialize(tr.getClient().getId().getClientName());
                Hibernate.initialize(tr.getDecisionrule().getId());
                //Hibernate.initialize(tr.getEscalationhistory().getEscalationtype().getEscalationTypeId());
                Hibernate.initialize(tr.getUserByBuyer());
                //Hibernate.initialize(tr.getDecisionrule().getId());
            }
            HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: @partlov:I am using Primefaces 3.5

Comment: Post code for your datatable and managed bean.

Comment: Also where are you calling `processModel_ = new TransactionLazyDataModel(criteria);`, in getter or init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multisort is working with sortMeta object